# Returning Hash Map object multiple values

Tags: java, object, hashmap

Hey there awesome people! Been at this for too long and can't find the answer. I need to display States (keys) and Capital objects; name, pop, and square Mi(values: string, int ,int). How can I display these? Runs null when I run normally(key, value) I try .get and have a static error. please help!?

```css
// Other class get set

public class Capital  {

    public String name;
    public int pop;
    public int sqM;

    public Capital(String nameIn, int popIn, int sqMIn){
        this.name = nameIn;
        this.pop = popIn;
        this.sqM = sqMIn;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getPop(){
        return pop;
    }
    public void setPop(int pop){
        this.pop = pop;
    }
    public int getSquare(){
        return sqM;
    }
    public void setSquare(int sqM){
        this.sqM = sqM;
    }
}
```

```html
public class App {
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        HashMap<String, Capital> StateCap = new HashMap<>();
        
        Capital capitalOne = new Capital("Montgomery", 258, 768);
        StateCap.put("Alabama", (capitalOne));
        Capital capitalTwo = new Capital("Juneau", 576, 94);
        StateCap.put("Alaska", (capitalTwo));
        
        Set<String> keys = StateCap.keySet();
        
         for (String state : keys) {
            //This is where I need help I believe.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are almost close. You just had to learn the functionality of `HashMap` a bit more.
Here you go:

```
    for (String state : keys) {
       // Get the value i.e. `Capital` object corresponding to the `key` i.e. `State`
        Capital cap = StateCap.get(state);
        System.out.println(cap.getName());
        System.out.println(cap.getPop());
        .
        .
        blah blah
    }
```

Also read about `entrySet()` method.

***N.B.:*** : Follow naming convention of variables (e.g: `StateCap` to `stateCap`).

Comment: Thank you sooo much! I should've figured this out, tried everything else I can think of. You are my new hero!